# Ionic templateURL not displaying file when changing states

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to Angular and Ionic and I'm having trouble using state navigation. I have a page that only has a header bar and a button. When I click the button, I want the page to now display a partial html file that I wrote, using $state.go(). When I click the button, the state definitely changes (the url changes and there is a sliding animation) but it only displays a blank page rather than my html file. I put the partial html file in the same directory as my index, so it's not a path error.

My code:

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="homePage" ng-controller = "homeController">

<ion-pane>

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-energized">
        <h1 class = "title">Home</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <button ng-click="logIn()"> Log In </button>                    

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

</ion-pane>
</body>
```

**homePage.js**

```
var homePage = angular.module("homePage", ['ionic','ui.router']);

homePage.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        url:"/",
        controller: 'homeController'            
    })
    .state('login',{
        url: '/login',                  
        templateURL: 'LoginPagePartial.html',
        controller: 'homeController'        
    })
    ;

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');   
}]);


homePage.controller('homeController', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', '$state', function($scope, $http, $location, $state){

$scope.logIn=function(){            
    $state.go('login');     
}
}]);
```

**LoginPagePartial.html**

```
<ion-view>
   <ion-content>        

        <h1>Welcome</h1>

   </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

If I replace "templateURL" and the file name with    `template: '<h1>Welcome</h1>'` then the page will change states and display "welcome" properly. The header bar displays properly regardless of what I do. Eventually I would like to make this file more complicated, so leaving it hardcoded in the state isn't an option. Is there something else required to make templateURL call a file properly? Or is there something else I have to do once the file is called in order to actually display the html?

Answer (score 0):

TemplateURL starts from www directory. So if your partial is in `www/app/templates` then you should write template url like `app/templates/LoginPagePartial.html`

Comment: Originally I used the path you suggested, but when I started having problems I moved the partial to the www folder, next to my index file, to eliminate any path error. In that case, I would just need to call to my partial, like I have it, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct if you moved the partial to the www folder.